# How to return getTexts for array of elements with isExisiting

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am aiming to return a set of texts from a single locator that shares three elements and they are stored in an array of elements name selector (being selector storing three elements)and before it returns texts I want them to pass isExisting() flag but it throws "TypeError: selector.isExisting is not a function" if I remove isExisting  part of code then it works fine and return the three text values. My code is:

```
  async function getTreeTexts(browser, sidebar, parentClass, treeClass, spanClass = 'caption') {
    //await browser.ideOpenSidebar(sidebar)
    var cl = c => c ? '.' + c : '';
    var selector  = await browser.$$(`${cl(parentClass)} .ace_tree${cl(treeClass)} .tree-row span${cl(spanClass)}`);
    await browser.ideOpenSidebar(sidebar)
    await selector.isExisting().then(async function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
        // Depending on the number of matches, items can be a string or an array of strings. Coerce to array.            
            let configs = [];
            for (let element of selector) {
                try {
                    let text = await element.getText();
                    configs.push(text);
                } catch (err) {
                    configs.push('[deleted]');
                }
            }
            return configs;
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone please assist me here if I am doing something wrong? (my guess is, isExisiting() not handling all three elements at the same time)

Comment: Seems like that's an array of webelements.  A webelement doesn't have a method for isExisting.  (neither does an array... you could check size/length/count) You can see all available methods for a single webelement here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html  Also if the element doesn't exist, it won't be added to the array so not sure why you'd check that condition.  Maybe you just want a webdriverwait?

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for your comments. I want to ensure those three elements exist once the sidebar is open (await browser.ideOpenSidebar(sidebar). I understand your point that most wait-related methods are specific to a single web element and hence I am looking for an alternative solution. I also tried passing isExisitng() in for loop to get through element to this flag one by one with no luck though

Comment: They may become stale after opening the side-bar.  You've basically got references to the nodes in the dom.  Once the DOM changes those references may become stale.  It sounds like that's what you want here.  try/catch a webdriverwait with explicit expected condition of "presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy".  Note that this will return an array if at least 1 item is located.  It's possible that more are being loaded... if that's the case, you'll get stale element exceptions when using the .getText() method.

Comment: If you know the number of elements ahead of time you can use expected condition of "numberOfElementsToBe"  If you are comparing before/after opening that side bar, you may need to gather and iterate the array before and after.